# BarbaJS doesn't animate the proper way and stops when enter homepage

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, barbajs

I want the animation that starts after entering the home page to start every time you enter it.

In addition, I want the transitions between pages to have a different type of animation.

I managed to do almost everything, but unfortunately, at the moment of transition between the project page and the main page, the animation stops. I do not understand why.

Here is the website: https://dzm11.github.io/portfolio/

**The error appear when you scroll down to "Kiddy" project and click VIEW PROJECT. Then page do animation that I want. Then You have to scroll up to the top of the website and click LOGO.** This is the time when the error happen. The black screen freeze and dont transform anyway.

JS code:

```
// entryAnimation
const text = document.querySelector(".preloader__text--content");
const strText = text.textContent;
const splitText = strText.split("");
text.textContent = "";

for (let i = 0; i < splitText.length; i++) {
text.innerHTML += "<span>" + splitText[i] + "</span>"
}

let char = 0;
let timer = setInterval(onTick, 50);

function onTick(){
  const span = text.querySelectorAll('span')[char]
  span.classList.add('fade');
  console.log(char)
  char++;
  if(char===splitText.length){
    complete();
    setTimeout(() => {
      preloader.classList.add('hide');
    }, 1500);

    return;
  }
}

function complete(){
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = null;
}

barba.use(barbaCss);

// barba.hooks.enter(() => {
//   window.scrollTo(0, 0);
// });

barba.init({
  transitions: [
{
      name: 'cover',
      to:{
        namespace: ['home', 'project']
      },
      leave(){},
      enter(){},
    },
    {
      name: 'entry',
      once(){}
    }
  ],
  views: [{
    namespace: 'home',
    beforeEnter(data) {
      preloader.classList.add('hide');
    }
  }]
});

const preloader = document.querySelector(".preloader");
```

HTML Code:

```
 <div class="preloader">

                <h1 class="fs-header-1 fw-demi preloader__text--content">H E N L O</h1>

        </div>
```

Css code:

```
.preloader {
    position: fixed;
    transform: translateY(0);
    background-color: var(--clr-neutral-900);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
    &.hide{
        transform: translateY(-100%);
    }

    &__text--content {
        overflow: hidden;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;

        span {
            transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            color: var(--clr-neutral-100);
            transform: translateY(100%);
        }

        span.fade {
            transform: translateY(0%);

        }
    }
}

.entry-once .preloader {
    transform: translateY(0%);
}

.entry-once-active,
.entry-once-active .preloader {
    transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1) 1.3s;
}

.entry-once-to .preloader {
    transform: translateY(100%);
}




.transition {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: var(--clr-neutral-900);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    z-index: 1;
}

.cover-leave-active,
.cover-enter-active,
.cover-leave-active .transition,
.cover-enter-active .transition {
    transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
}

.cover-leave .transition {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.cover-leave-to .transition {
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.cover-enter .transition {
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.cover-enter-to .transition {
    transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

I tried almost everything and I think I just dont understand the mechanics of BarbaJS